# add column and put desired value depending on the condition

Tags: python, pandas

[screenshot of the dataframe table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrRoM.png)

I want to have another column name final grade that will get the average grade and checks if the average grade is greater than > or equal = to 75. And if so put 'Passed' and if not put 'FAILED'

```
df_exams['Final Grade'] = 'PASSED' if df_exams.loc[(df_exams['Average Grade'] >= 75)] else 'FAIL'
```

Can someone help me I am a newbie and want to be a Data Analyst. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please replace the images with formatted code/text in the question. See also: [ask] and [How to format code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/967621)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use apply with a lambda function. The example below is from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-apply-in-pandas-lambda-functions-with-multiple-if-statements/). Hope it helps!

`df['Result'] = df['Maths'].apply(lambda x: 'Pass' if x>=5 else 'Fail')`

Comment: It works but it's an inefficient way to do it...

Comment: Do you know how to do it efficiently? I really want to improve my programming skills